# PostGis and datatypes WKT

Tags: database, postgresql, postgis, wkt, wkb

I dont't have any experience with the geographics databases so I hope that you be patiente with me, the thing is: I know that the datatype geography is used if all you care about is measuring distances and lengths and you have data from all over the world and the datatype geometry is used is best if you are pretty comfortable with spatial reference systems or you are dealing with localized data where
all your data fits in a single spatial reference system (SRID), or you need to do a lot of spatial processing (that's what I read in chapter 3 of the documentation of postgis) and I saw on the link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_data_types.htm the following datatypes: point, line, lseg, box, path, path, polygon and circle. And then I saw the documentation again of the postgis on the section 4.1.3 SQL-MM Part 3 about the following types with the extension well-know text: circularString, compoundCurve, curvePolygon, multiCurve, multiSurface. What I don't understand is: what is the difference between these datatypes?

Comment: It's better to ask at [Geographic Information Systems](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) and delete your question here.

Comment: Ok man thanks for the tip, I'll do it.